How do I determine how much wire, and how big an electromagnetic motor should be?
I am attempting to build an electromagnetic motor for my skateboard. I would like to use the current, standard skateboard wheels it came with, so the motor needs to be relatively small (40-46 mm). I would like it to be able to move 150 lbs.

have you considered buying a motor?

Why does everyone who asks a question about a motor driving wheels think that the weight it has to move is a useful metric? You need to figure out how much torque it needs to provide, the weight involved is only pretty distantly related to that.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

a coworkers electric longboard has two motors that are each 50mm dIameter and 55mm long.

https://hackaday.com/2024/04/05/a-drone-motor-does-e-bikes/

You will not be able to build a motor yourself that will come even remotely close to matching the performance (torque/volume, torque/mass, torque/power consumption) of a prebuilt motor.

@Hearth because I'm 16 and have never taken a physics class.
